# I would like to unzip as different file name

Tags: unzip

Ok i need to extract a zip archive named 'example.zip' but i would like to extract it as a different file name, not 'example' being my folder name, how could i extract a zip archive using unzip called 'example.zip' and extract it as the folder name 'examplefold'

Answer (score 23):

By default, `unzip` extracts the content of the archive directly into the current directory.

You can specify a different target directory where to extract the files using the `-d` option:

```
unzip example.zip -d /path/to/wherever/you/want/the/archive/to/get/extracted
```

---

Or if the archive itself contains a folder `example` which you want to extract to the current directory, but with a different name, you must manually rename it to `examplefold` afterwards:

```
unzip example.zip && mv example examplefold
```

Comment: if there exists a `example` folder already then does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have some zip files with these names:

```
2.zip, 25.zip, 45.zip, ..., 10352.zip
```

Also, in each zip file there is a folder which is called `tmp`. I will write a bash file (say zz.sh) with this content:

```
for zipName in 2 25 45 65 85 110 264 1000 10352
do        
    unzip $zipName.zip
    mv tmp tmp_$zipName 
done
```

Then run the file by:

```
bash zz.sh
```